# php, JSON: cURL object not editable with PHP

Tags: php, json, curl

I am trying to pull a JSON object from another page and then break it into pieces and values to my php document's variables and populate the page with them.

The issue I am running into is that while the curl_exec call prints the JSON object, I cannot do anything to it from that point on.  Below is my code:

```
$json_url = "localhost:8080/query";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json')); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $json_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user.":".$pass);  
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
var_dump ($result);

$curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
$curl_error = curl_error($ch);

curl_close($ch);

// ON SUCCESS

$json_a =  $result[10];
var_dump ($json_a);
```

Here is a sample of a piece of the result:

```
 ["4"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1325003843) [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(47) [1]=> array(17) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(0) [1]=> int(1) } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(17) [1]=> int(44) } [2]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(3) [1]=> int(4) } [3]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(3) [1]=> int(4) } [4]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(3) [1]=> int(4) } [5]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(3) [1]=> int(4) } [6]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(3) [1]=> int(4) } [7]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(3) [1]=> int(4) } [8]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(3) [1]=> int(4) } [9]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(3) [1]=> int(4) } [10]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(3) [1]=> int(4) } [11]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(3) [1]=> int(4) } [12]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(3) [1]=> int(4) } [13]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(2) [1]=> int(3) } [14]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(2) [1]=> int(3) } [15]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(2) [1]=> int(3) } [16]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(2) [1]=> int(3) } } } }
```

The var_dump ($result); returns int(1) and the other var_dump returns NULL.  The curl_exec actually prints the JSON object, so I know tat it is at least grabbing it. Thanks so much for any help you might offer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also just do something like

```
$json_url = "localhost:8080/query";
// $protocol should be the protocol used, ie. 'ftp://', 'http://' or 'https://'
//  to produce an URL like 'ftp://user:pass@localhost:8080/query'
$result = file_get_contents($protocol . $user.":".urlencode($pass) . '@' . $json_url);

if($result !== false) { // ON SUCCESS
  $result = json_decode($result, true);
  var_dump ($result);

  if(isset($result[10])) { // If index 10 of $result exists
    $json_a =  $result[10];
    var_dump ($json_a);
  }
} else {
  // error occured
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  Would this replace the whole code segement above? Also, what would $protocol be?  Thanks so much and let me know if you need any other inforamtion from me!

Comment: Well, depends what your `$json_url` contains. If you could include it in the code above, along with the var_dumps, I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Ok, i updated the question and then also added part of the result.  It is a really huge object, so it would be tough to include the whole thing...

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect the functionality of the code in the question.

Comment: Ok, great! The result of the var_dump of $results works great. I did notice when I tried to validate the JSON object that is output here, I get an error at the beginning.  I am updating my question with the intial portion of the JSON object.

Comment: That worked perfectly!  The only difference I had to make was that index [10] was actually within index [1]  so when I switched it to [1] [10] it worked perfectly!  Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm glad if I was any help, although my answer didn't really answer your original question as much as propose an alternative solution. And a note to self should always be to check and debug your arrays and their indices.

Answer (score 3):

With CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER set to false, curl_exec returns only true or false.
Set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER to true and curl_exec should return the result for you.

Comment: in other words, if returntransfer is false, curl will OUTPUT the results to the client instead of returning it to the script.

Comment: Ok, thanks so much!  Now, when I decode $ch, the first var_dump prints "array(2).." and then the JSON object as an array.  But my second var_dump shows as Null still.

Comment: Could you post the output from the first var_dump? Looks like `$result` is an array with only two items in it, so referencing index probably should return null?

Comment: Well, it looks like your problem is that there is no index `10` in `$result`... Are you absolutely sure there should be?

Comment: yeah, actually that was just the first portion of it.  Index 10 just contains information that is not super good for posting.  Here is the initial part of it:   ["10"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (17) { ["0"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1325003844) [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(31) [1]=> string(19) "ONBOARD TEMPERATURE" } }

That is just the first part of the index.  Thanks!